# How to fix "Attempted import error"? / What audio player should I use for a Hybrid React-Native app?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, web, react-native-track-player

I tried using `react-native-track-player` and it runs fine on android, but on the web, I get the following error:

```
./node_modules/react-native-track-player/lib/hooks.js
Attempted import error: 'STATE_BUFFERING' is not exported from './index' (imported as 'TrackPlayer').
```

I yet at this moment don't know how to fix this, but I will be grateful if someone knows how may I fix it or if there is a great alternative for an audio player that can be used for both **web** and **android**, and also be **very lightweight**.

Package versions:

```
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.4",
"react-native-track-player": "^1.2.3",
"typescript": "^4.1.3",
```

The tutorial I am following: https://medium.com/finimize-engineering/building-a-global-audio-player-in-react-native-dd065fc64b02

Comment: React-native components generally don't work outside "native" environments. Maybe [react-native-web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web) can help get your app running in a web container (versus native).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll try doing that.